# C# windows app Minimize in system tray error

Tags: c#

Hi Friends i have written the program for minimize the form into system tray it is working fine for the minimize and in tray i can see new icon is appeared.
and in double click it restores, But the error is when i restore the form into its normal state then some labels are automatically goes visible false and the timer i have used in form that timer automatically stops please let me know if anyone have faced the same issue and have any idea about this issue.
please refer below code

```
  private void User_Projects_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

        try
        {

            bool Mousepointontaskbar = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Contains(Cursor.Position);
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized && Mousepointontaskbar)
            {
                notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Application;
                notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Tracker Has bin Minimized in System Tray";
                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
                this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
                //this.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(User_Projects_SizeChanged);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private void User_Projects_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Resize += new EventHandler(User_Projects_SizeChanged);
    }

    private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
         this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
            this.Visible = true;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the point of 'this.Resize += new EventHandler(User_Projects_SizeChanged);' ? Everytime you resize the form, you attach a new event handler that calls 'User_Projects_SizeChanged', which means that you will get a ton of calls to the same method

Comment: removed the this.resize but there is no change in the output still i am getting the same error

Comment: I think we need the full c# source file for your window. It seems to me that you are struggling with how to used events

Comment: i think  you can refer yourself that the Form Minimize function in  system tray and restore to its original state will not work for the timer when you  take the timer on the windows form and you can start the timer and minimize it in system tray when you restore to its original state you will see timer get stop's automaticaly